# Google charts wrong data sorting

Tags: php, charts, google-visualization

I want to sort data by date but for some reason it's not sorted properly, example

```
['Sep 28',2],
['Sep 27',2],
['Oct 02',1],
['Oct 01',1],
['Sep 28',1],
['Sep 27',4],
['Sep 26',2],
```

So it's not sorted by date.

I have get data from databse with php

```
foreach ($array as $row){
    echo "['".date('M d', strtotime($row['date']))."',".$row['views']."],";
}
```

And data is sorted correctly, here is example of charts and you can see problem

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bmzGdb

Comment: Can you show the SQL your using?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM views_stats WHERE content_id = ".$id." AND submitter = ".$user." ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 30`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the data is resulting in a string in javascript, so it will sort like a string.
instead, use a real date in javascript.
something like...

```
foreach ($array as $row){
    echo "[new Date(".strtotime($row['date'])." * 1000),".$row['views']."],";
}
```

then you can format the date for the axis using option...

```
hAxis: {
  format: 'MMM dd'
}
```

**UPDATE**

since the format does not include time, the x-axis may repeat the labels.
to prevent, use custom ticks.

```
hAxis: {
  format: 'MMM dd',
  ticks: data.getDistinctValues(0)
}
```

where `data` is the google data table...

**UPDATE 2**

another option for ticks is to build your own, based on the date range of the chart...

```
var oneDay = (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
var hAxisTicks = [];
var dateRange = data.getColumnRange(0);
for (var i = dateRange.min.getTime(); i <= dateRange.max.getTime(); i = i + oneDay) {
  hAxisTicks.push(new Date(i));
}

hAxis: {
  format: 'MMM dd',
  ticks: hAxisTicks
}
```

Comment: Yes but now another problem is there, check screenshot
https://i.imgur.com/1vwo80Z.jpg
the same day is repeated several time.

Comment: Here is charts https://i.imgur.com/K64MI5t.jpg
I think is better to make it in this way `echo "['".$row['date']."',".$row['views']."],\n";` here is result https://i.imgur.com/bvi4Txu.jpg but question is how then format day and remove year? hAxis: {format: 'MMM dd'} will not work in this way

Comment: see __UPDATE 2__, this should create consistent ticks, the problem with the above comment, it has to be a real date to use `format` (not string)...

Comment: Hmm `dateRange.min.getTime is not a function`

Comment: first column must be a date, not a string, are you still using? --> `echo "[new Date(".strtotime($row['date'])." * 1000),".$row['views']."],";`

Comment: No i have `echo "['".$row['date']."',".$row['views']."],\n";` output `['2018-10-25',2],`

Comment: `'2018-10-25'` is a string, not a date -- for `ticks` to work, must be a real date

Comment: So should be `echo "[new Date(".strtotime($row['date'])." * 1000),".$row['views']."],";` this is result https://i.imgur.com/hLTCh38.jpg

Comment: Yeah but actualy again display date which is not in database, because i post screenshot, i don't have date 19.10,20.10,21.10 but on chart you can see it i think should be hidden... this is what i need https://i.imgur.com/bvi4Txu.jpg but only to change format date to `Oct. 10` for example

Comment: Or maybe just set value 0 for date which is not in database.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution, if anyone have same problem here is solution.
First you need to find first and last day from database, example `MIN(date) MAX(date)` and than...

```
$date_from = $rows['date_from'];
$date_from = strtotime($date_from);
$date_to  = $rows['date_to'];
$date_to = strtotime($date_to);

for ($i=$date_from; $i<=$date_to; $i+=86400)
{
  $vl = 0;
  $dt = date("Y-m-d", $i);
  foreach ($array as $row)
  {
    if ( $row["date"] == $dt)
    {
      $dt = $row["date"];
      $vl = $row["views"];
    }
  }
 echo "[new Date(".strtotime($dt)." * 1000),".$vl."],\n";
}
```

This example is working together with @WhiteHat answer above

[image]